# Problems making REST POST requests to SP-Hosted App with Postman

Tags: rest, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am facing problems when making REST calls of type POST to my Sharepoint Hosted app with Postman in Chrome. GET type calls work fine.

For example, I want to make the following call on my app to get the changes on a list (and yes, this is a POST call weird enough):

```
https://mysite-AppGUID.sharepoint.com/sites/developer2/MySharepointApp/_api/Lists/getbytitle('lstRollen')/getChanges
```

Response is the following:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "-2130575251, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
    "message": {
        "lang": "en-US",
        "value": "The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again."
    }
}
```

Googling learned me that I have to add a X-RequestDigest header with the value obtained from the POST call:

`../_api/contextinfo`

Indeed I get a value there as expected but when I add it to the headers, it still does not work. Am I missing something here? Really need this to work!!!!

Comment: Can you reproduce this w/o postman? If so, try to see what headers are sent with fiddler.

Comment: In Fiddler I got the same responses. Anyway, problem is solved now, retried and it was working, not sure what went wrong...

Comment: I hate those problems... You have to sleep one night, and then the problem magically goes away... ;)